# Ruby on Rails でのユーザー情報と投稿の紐付けに関して

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

■前提・実現したいこと

Ruby on Rails で
複数のユーザーが記事を投稿できる簡単なブログを作っています。
誰でもemailとpasswordを使ってログインし、
記事を投稿できるようにしています。

そして今実装したいのは
「記事のページにいくと記事を投稿した人が誰かをemailアドレスで表示する」
ということです。

例えば

Aさんがa@yahoo.co.jpでログインし投稿した記事には
「書いた人：a@yahoo.co.jp」
と表示し、

Bさんがb@yahoo.co.jpでログインし投稿した記事には
「書いた人：b@yahoo.co.jp」
と表示したいです。

userに関してはdeviseを利用しています。

画像で例をあげると、
ログインしてから下のように記事を投稿すると

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

記事のページではこのように書いた人を表示させたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また編集したときにはemailの表示は変えなくて
いいようにもしたいです。

つまり
Aさんがa@yahoo.co.jpでログインし投稿した記事には
「書いた人：a@yahoo.co.jp」
と表示しますが、この記事をBさんが編集しても
「書いた人：a@yahoo.co.jp」のまま
という感じです。

=================================

これを実装するにあたり
まずpostにhas_many:usersを加えて関連付けし、

記事のデータ(post)に
user_idというカラムを追加し、

これにログインして記事を投稿する人のidを
代入して保存し、viewのhtml.erbの部分で
「投稿者：<% @post.user.email%>」
としようとしましたが上手くいきませんでした。

ログインし、実際に記事を投稿しようとしたときに
以下のようなエラーが出ました。

■発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■該当のソースコード

コントローラーは下のようになります。

●application_controller.rbに
以下のようにコードを書き加え

before_action :set_current_user, only: [:create]

```
def set_current_user
@current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user.id])
end
```

●posts_controller.rbにはこのように書いています。

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
@post = Post.all.order(created_at: 'desc')
end

def show
@post = Post.find_by(params[:id])
@user = User.find_by(id: @post.user_id)
end

def new
@post = Post.new
end
```

def create
  @post = Post.new(
    content: params[:content],
    user_id: @current_user.id
  )
    if @post.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

```
def edit
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
if @post.update(post_params)
redirect_to post_path
else
render 'edit'
end
end

def post_params
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
end
```

●show.html.erbに書いた部分は以下です。

```
<p>書いた人:<%= @post.user.email %> </p>
```

●modelのpost.rbも載せておきます。

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
validates :title, presence: true
validates :body, presence: true
has_many :users
end
```

●dbはこのようになっています。

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171209035931) do

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "title"
t.text "body"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "user_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "email", default: "", null: false
t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
t.string "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end

end
```

■試したこと

↓のサイトに書かれている通りにやってみました。
https://qiita.com/you88/items/63ad0b9c07da4323fe26

しかし上手くいかず、色々と調べたり
変数いじったりしてみたのですが解決しません。

■補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

補足というか思ったの事なのですが
エラーのidがnil Classとなっていますが、
そもそも＠current_userにログインしている
ユーザーの値が入っていないのではないか
と思っております。

困っています。
よろしくお願いいたします。

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

**追記**

ご返信ありがとうございます。

ご指摘の通りhas_manyは間違っていたと思います。
ありがとうございます。
ですが、ほかの部分でつまっているので
もう少しお力をお貸しいただけたらと思います。

現在このように記事を
投稿しようとしたら
このようなエラーがでるという状況です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上にも書いたのですが、
コントローラーは

application_controller.rbでは

before_action :set_current_user, only: [:create]

def set_current_user
  @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

post_controller.rbでは

def create
  @post = Post.new(
    post_params,
    user_id: current_user.id
  )
    if @post.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

としています。

解決策があれば
教えて戴けたらと思います。
どうかよろしくお願いします。

==================================================

**追記２**

ありがとうございます。
前者の方で試してみることにしました。

しかし、ログインして
記事を投稿しようとしたところ、
次のようにcurrent_user.idがnilだと
言われてしまいました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ログインしている状態でしか
投稿できない様にしているので、
ログインしていることは確実なのですが、
なぜこのようになってしまうのでしょうか？

勝手な想像ですが、
gem deviseを利用している場合、

application_controller.rbの

before_action :set_current_user, only: [:create]

def set_current_user
  @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

という部分が使えないとかいう
ことがあったりするのでしょうか？

何度もすみませんが、
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

**追記３**

application_controller.rbにて

before_action :set_current_user, only: [:create]

def set_current_user
  @current_user = current_user　
end
としたところ、記事の投稿でエラーがでることは
なくなりました！

しかし、各記事のページに行くと

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

となってしまいます。

これはすなわちpostにuser情報が
くっついていないということなんでしょうか？
どうすれば良いのでしょうか...
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

Postモデルで、

```
has_many :users
```

ではなく

```
belongs_to :user
```

としてください。

自分のテーブルにある「他のテーブルのIDを記録したカラム」で他のテーブルを参照する時は`belongs_to`、他のテーブルにある「自分のテーブルのIDを記録したカラム」で他のテーブルを参照する時は`has_many`または`has_one`(1対多か1対1か)になります。

---

エラーになってるのは、`Post.new`の引数が間違っている(コードのような引数の渡し方が出来ない)からです。

単純には

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
@post.user_id = @current_user.id
```

で動きますが、質問のようなことがやりたいのであれば、

UserモデルにPostへのリレーションを追加し、

```
class User < ...
  has_many :posts
end
```

そのリレーションを利用してPostを作った方がいいと思います

```
@current_user.posts.build(post_params)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。まだ解決できていないので追記の部分を見てくださればと思います。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。仰る通りにやってみようとしたのですが、別のエラーがでてしまいました。内容は追記しております。何かわかりませんでしょうか？重ねがさね申し訳ありません、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: nilに関して、少し書き換えると上手くいきましたが、次はページ表示のところでエラーがでてしまいました。これはどうすればよいのでしょうか...？

Comment: 追記追記で次々質問をされると、質問と回答の対応がわかりにくくなってしまいます。一旦自分で考えた上で、あらためて整理した内容を質問してもらえませんか。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。色々試したうえで再度質問させていただきます。